# Random errors when using rexec

Tags: linux, unix, network-programming

I have a very odd error when using rexec. The code is very simple, I am just calling rexec in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int main() {
  char buffData[1024];
  int i;
  ssize_t j;
  char * l_ahost = "cwp01";
  struct servent * l_servInfo = getservbyname("exec", "tcp");
  for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    int err = rexec(&l_ahost, l_servInfo->s_port, NULL, NULL, "echo -n .", NULL);
    if (err <= 0) {
      perror("Rexec error");
    } else {
      if (read(err, buffData, 1024) > 0) printf ("'%c' %d\n", *buffData, i);
      close(err);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
muftak : > gcc tst_rexec.c ; ./a.out
    '.' 0
    '.' 1
    '.' 2
    '.' 3
    '.' 4
    ...
    '.' 47
    '.' 48
    '.' 49
    cwp01.eurocontrol.fr: Connection reset by peer
    Rexec error: Illegal seek
    '.' 51
    '.' 52
    '.' 53
    '.' 54
    ...
```

Why does rexec work correctly almost always, but not always ? Non determinist behaviour for such a simple case disturbs me a lot. I have no clue of where to search an explanation for this (except stackoverflow, of course).

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know that much about TCP and even less about rexec.    have you tried the command version yet.   your code suggests you could use the rexec (1) as opposed to rexec (3).

good luck.

Comment: I have the same result with command line:
perl -e 'foreach $i (0..1999) {$a = `rexec -a cwp01 echo -n .`;print "$a $i\n"}'
...
. 1776
cwp01.eurocontrol.fr: Connection reset by peer
rexec: Error in rexec system call,
rexec: (The following system error may itself be in error)
rexec: Illegal seek
 1777

rexec: Error in read from remote host: Connection reset by peer
. 1778
...

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read the man page for rexec to know why you *must* not use it.

Second, "non determinist behaviour" is quite common in network programming (and it is a big difference with local programming and a reason why fully distributed systems, where you do not even know that code is run remotely, is very hard to achieve). From the error message, it looks like the server cwp01.eurocontrol.fr simply rebooted during your test.

Comment: I fully agree with the first point, I am pushing to stop using rexec. I understand non determinist behaviour for complex system, but this is not the case, and there was no reboot. The problem is very easy to reproduce here.

Comment: "Easy to reproduce" and "Non determinist behaviour" (your own words) are quite contradictory. If it always fail at the 49th iteration, it *is* deterministic.